# laravel 5.6 Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::registered()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send verification email and here is the code that gives me the error

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'We sent you an activation code. 
            Check your email and click on the link to verify.');
}
```

It give me the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::registered() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /home/bassel/book_donation/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 37

In order to solve it I added  to the RegisterController the following:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request;
```

but that did not solve the problem, how can i solve it?

Comment: Try changing "use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request;" to "use Illuminate\Http\Request;"

Answer (score 2):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class .... 
{
    ...
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'We sent you an activation code. 
                Check your email and click on the link to verify.');
    }
}
```

That `Request $request` now says a class of `Illuminate\Http\Request` must be passed, as that is the instance that will be passed to this method.